# Can we use other than the "data(id)" for rendering labels in cytoscape.js ? i.e without using "data" object?

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I was just wondering if we can use something like

```
 label: "ID(id)"
```

where nodes object would be like :

```
nodes: [
            { 
              data: { label: "IP 1", type: "ip" }, 
              label:['EC2'],
              ID:{id:'1'}
            }
        ]
```

I don't see any particular documentation that specifies the use of "data" key to render.

By trying above code,it just prints it as a string and not evaluating the given expression.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From what I could try out, we cannot use anything other than the "data()" function inside any of the selector object's members(only for which accepts a function, some only accept strings)
So to manipulate any data, we would have to keep the wanted values under "data" and use any javascript function to return our desired output.

For example :

```
   label: function (node) { 
              return `${node.data("labels")} ${node.data("id")}` 
            }
```

Here lables and id are your keys and we can use any function to do manipulate the output.

Comment: Nice answer, you may check to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is some `input` (live-code) that is requested. It demonstrates the use of

```
label: "ID(id)"
```

that does not produce expected result (no evaluation).

```js
var data = {
  "nodes": [{
      data: {
        label: "IP_1",
        type: "ip"
      },
      label: ['EC2'],
      ID: {
        id: '1'
      }
    },
  ],
  "edges": []
}


//console.log(data);//uncomment this to see file content

var cy = cytoscape({
  elements: data,
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),
  style: [{
    selector: "node",
    style: {
      shape: "hexagon",
      "background-color": "red",
      //label: "data(id)",
      label: "ID(id)",  /* No evaluation */
      //label: function (node) {return `${node.data("label")} ${node.data("type")}`}  /* Evaluation OK */
    }
  }],
  layout: {
    name: "grid"
  }
});
```

```css
#cy {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/2.7.10/cytoscape.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the LIVE code that uses the `snippet code` from the answer provided by @Poornima T.

It can be executed and the result is as expected.

```js
var data = {
  "nodes": [{
      data: {
        label: "IP_1",
        type: "ip"
      },
      label: ['EC2'],
      ID: {
        id: '1'
      }
    },
  ],
  "edges": []
}


//console.log(data);//uncomment this to see file content

var cy = cytoscape({
  elements: data,
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),
  style: [{
    selector: "node",
    style: {
      shape: "hexagon",
      "background-color": "red",
      //label: "data(id)",
      //label: "ID(id)",  /* No evaluation */
      label: function (node) {return `${node.data("label")} ${node.data("type")}`}  /* Evaluation OK */
    }
  }],
  layout: {
    name: "grid"
  }
});
```

```css
#cy {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/2.7.10/cytoscape.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```